# How do I change the publish module version number in my Powershell script generated by Visual Studio?

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, msdeploy

I'm following documentation on how to deploy my .NET Core application to IIS using MSDeploy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis-with-msdeploy

After creating a publish profile in Visual Studio, a powershell script is generated. The documentation tells me that I need to update the publish module version number from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2-beta2. I've been looking through these files that have been generated [app name]-publish.ps1 and publish-module.psm1, and I don't see where the publish module version is set.

Is this publish module version set in the code or somewhere else?